# How to use a Durandal view as a template?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) developed using ASP .net MVC and Durandal. 
I have a view `Test.html` and corresponding view `Test.js`.

My requirement is I want to display this view within another view (using as a template) and also display this view for a route - say `http://localhost/MyApp/#Test`.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

My problem is, in the view I need to return the instance of my view model if I want to display the view for the route. And if I do this, I cannot use this as a template within another view.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this by using the Durandal compose knockout binding.

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: 'views/myview.html', model: object }"></div>
```

Here you can bind anything you want to object as your view.

See #3 here for more information: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html#composing-explicit-models-and-views

Comment: if this was helpful, please accept it as the answer

Comment: I will check and let you know